# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'messageParts[0].toString')?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that looks like this in the console:

```
Object

    date: "2017-04-20T06:44:22Z"
    productId: "MYPROID"
    state: 3
    transactionId: "100004560029ghjg56"
    __proto__: —
```

I'm printing this on console using the code below:

```
inAppPurchase
  .restorePurchases()
  .then(function (data) {

    console.log(data);


    /*
      [{
        transactionId: ...
        productId: ...
        state: ...
        date: ...
      }]
    */
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

I'm trying to access the `transactionId` in that array so i did this:

```
inAppPurchase
  .restorePurchases()
  .then(function (data) {


    console.log(data.transactionId);

    /*
      [{
        transactionId: ...
        productId: ...
        state: ...
        date: ...
      }]
    */
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

but that returns this error inthe console:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'messageParts[0].toString')?
```

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is an `Array` as you mentioned, and as printed by the `console.log`.

You need to access the first item of this array:

```
console.log(data[0].transactionId);
```